# PHP with Kafka - rdkafka

Tags: php, apache-kafka, librdkafka

Iam dealing with kafka and php, Im beginner  the kafka has been set upped correctly on the server,

now am on local
I have installed:
librdkafka.dll on xamp/php
and php_rdkafka.dll on xamp/php/ext

and i added this on php.ini:

extension=php_rdkafka.dll

then, i have created a php page contains this code:

```
$topic_name = '???';
$conf = new RdKafka\Conf();
$conf->set('metadata.broker.list', $broker_list);
$conf->set('enable.idempotence', 'true');
$conf->set('group.id', $topic_name);
$conf->set('sasl.username', "???");
$conf->set('sasl.mechanism', "PLAIN");
$conf->set('sasl.password', "???");
$conf->set('log_level', (string) LOG_DEBUG);
$conf->set('debug', 'all');
$producer = new RdKafka\Producer($conf);
$producer->addBrokers($broker_list);
$topic = $producer->newTopic($topic_name);
$topic->produce(RD_KAFKA_PARTITION_UA, 0, "Message Test");
$producer->poll(0);
$result = $producer->flush(10000);
```

but nothing returns on stream

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you trying to connect to confluent cloud?

I would add to your conf your security protocol, as you indicate sasl. eg $conf->set('security.protocol','sasl_ssl');

I would think you would not need to indicate the brokers in the producer, as you have already done this in the config. I am presuming your broker list is a csv formatted file that include host and port number?

Comment: the broker list is a string contains host and port number, and i added the security protocol you sent removed the broker in produce, but still nothing on the stream

Comment: Can you try the sample in this web linik, add your sasl options and try again. https://arnaud.le-blanc.net/php-rdkafka-doc/phpdoc/rdkafka.examples-producer.html

Comment: I have had another go with your code and i have disabled the group.id (as this is for consumers). added security.protocol as mentioned earlier. also added $conf->set('acks', 'all'), then turned off your debug option and voila! I now have a message in my topic.

Comment: thank you bro it worked, still cant install rdkafka on linux server, could you help me on this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68129230/install-rdkafka-on-ubuntu

Comment: Funny enough i have just done this on debian 10. So pretty much the same, i build my own using these steps: These two git sites should point you on the right path. [librdkafka](https://github.com/edenhill/librdkafka.git) and [php-rdkafka](https://github.com/arnaud-lb/php-rdkafka.git). Copy these and they should get you on the right path. As i have now added rdkafka.so to my php.ini file and everything works perfect.

Comment: Hi Ahmed
these links should help you make progress my friend. [librdkafka](https://github.com/edenhill/librdkafka.git) and [php-rdkafka](https://github.com/arnaud-lb/php-rdkafka.git)
When you run configure, make sure you run with --install-deps for librdkafka
Hope that helps you out.