# Install rdkafka on Ubuntu

Tags: php, linux, ubuntu, apache-kafka, librdkafka

Im trying to install rdkafka on a drupal 9 site hosted in a linux server, i tried this commands

```
sudo apt install php-pear
sudo apt-get install -y librdkafka-dev
sudo pecl install rdkafka
```

then I added this to php.ini

```
extension=rdkafka.so
```

but when print phpinfo(); rdkafka library isn't installed yet

Comment: I have sent a response to this issue on your other kafka query
[php kafka](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68010016/php-with-kafka-rdkafka/68017004?noredirect=1#comment120413183_68017004)

Comment: I tried all these steps and i have same problem, when i try to launch composer install i get this error: ```PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'rdkafka.so' (tried: /usr/lib/php/20190902/rdkafka.so (/usr/lib/php/20190902/rdkafka.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory), /usr/lib/php/20190902/rdkafka.so.so (/usr/lib/php/20190902/rdkafka.so.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory)) in Unknown on line 0```

Answer (score 0):

I have always found downloading and building the libraries myself easier.
Please follow the link in my original response. These installed the rdkafka.so into the mentioned php build library.